# Creating linear gradient mask from image using opencv

Tags: opencv

Is there any existing function that can create a gradient mask from an image?

I need this to remove a background gradient from a night sky image where the light pollution makes a gradient. Subtracting a blurred image is not an option due to the non-sky element in the image.
[image]

I was planning to run some numerical optimization to estimate the gradient parameters but if there is an existing function I don't need to spend time on this.

Comment: "gradient mask" is an oxymoron. masks are binary. show your input data. and don't be vague. "non-sky element" is being vague.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz Thanks! That's a good idea. I added a picture. I would like to remove the gradient from the image.

Comment: if you can bear imperfections around the tree line, subtract a median filter.